# Capturing a csv download as an array load instead using Google Script

Tags: javascript, csv, google-sheets

I've spent a few days searching around the site looking for what I was after, but unable to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Basically, I want to be able to call this URL, and instead of it starting a CSV download, I want to capture the output using google script to populate a google spreadsheet:

http://www.footytips.com.au/cfm/ft/sub/downloadLadder.cfm?sort=2&fg=competitions&ff=default&sportId=2&page=1&competitionId=220363&gameType=tips&gameCompId=46295&view=ladderScores&round=1

Basically, I'm not quite sure where to start.  I wasn't able to debug the javascript in-browser effectively to find if a direct path to the CSV is produced at any time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could use google's fusion tables:

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows

Comment: It's not so much the storing and sorting the data that is the problem, it's more how to actually load the csv which is downloaded into an array, _instead_ of it triggering the download.  Once I can do that, I can sort the data out.